Terraform with Self Agent Host Linux in ADO - Service Principals Variables issues
I am using my Az Cli login with addSpnToEnvironment. This supposed to populate ARM_* variables
Basically, all the echos I placed to show me values is actually displaying nothing.
I've a Linux Ubuntu as self host agent.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main  # Trigger the pipeline on any changes to the 'main' branch

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main  # Enable the pipeline to run for pull requests targeting the 'main' branch

parameters:
  - name: environment  # Define a parameter for the environment (dev, sit, prod)
    displayName: "Select Environment"
    type: string
    default: dev  # Default environment is set to 'dev'
    values:
      - dev
      - sit
      - prod

jobs:
- job: terraform_deploy
  displayName: "Deploy Infrastructure using Terraform"  # The job name and description

  pool: teste
  

  steps:
    - checkout: self  # Checkout the repository containing the Terraform code

    - task: UseDotNet@2  # Ensure .NET SDK is installed, required for running some scripts
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.x'  # Use .NET 6.x
        installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

    # Install Azure CLI
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Install Azure CLI"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
          curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg > /dev/null
          AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
          echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y azure-cli

    # Then proceed with Terraform steps


    # Install Terraform CLI on the agent if it is not already installed
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Install Terraform"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common
          wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
          echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
          sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform

    # Login to Azure CLI using a Service Connection
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Azure CLI login'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Azure ARM Connection'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        addSpnToEnvironment: true
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          echo "Successfully logged into Azure CLI"

    # Test if Env Variables are okay
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Check Environment Variables"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "ARM_CLIENT_ID: $ARM_CLIENT_ID"
          echo "ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"
          echo "ARM_TENANT_ID: $ARM_TENANT_ID"
          echo "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"

    # Initialize Terraform with the correct backend configuration for the environment
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Terraform Init"
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(servicePrincipalId)
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(servicePrincipalKey)
        ARM_TENANT_ID: $(tenantId)
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(subscriptionId)
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "ARM_CLIENT_ID: $ARM_CLIENT_ID"
          echo "ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"
          echo "ARM_TENANT_ID: $ARM_TENANT_ID"
          echo "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
          export TF_LOG=DEBUG
          cd project/terraform
          terraform init -backend-config="backend-config-${{ parameters.environment }}.tfvars"
    # Run 'terraform plan' to generate and display the changes Terraform will make
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Terraform Plan"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd project/terraform
          export TF_LOG=DEBUG
          terraform plan -var-file="${{ parameters.environment }}.tfvars"

    # Run Terraform Apply only for dev and sit environments
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Terraform Apply"
      condition: or(eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'dev'), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'sit'))
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd project/terraform
          export TF_LOG=DEBUG
          terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file="${{ parameters.environment }}.tfvars"

    # Publish Terraform state file as an artifact if the apply fails
    - publish: terraform/errored.tfstate
      artifact: terraform_state
      condition: failed()  # Only publish the state if the job fails

    # Optionally, send a success or failure notification (custom script)
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Send Notification"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "Deployment of environment ${{ parameters.environment }} completed."

# Separate job to handle production manually
- job: terraform_apply_prod
  displayName: "Manual Apply for Production"
  dependsOn: terraform_deploy
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'prod')  # Only runs if 'prod' environment is selected
  pool: teste

  steps:
    # Manual apply for production after approval in the Azure DevOps UI
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: "Azure Login"
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: "Azure ARM Connection"  # Specify your ARM service connection here
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          echo "Successfully logged into Azure"

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Terraform Apply for Production"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd project/terraform
          terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file="prod.tfvars"

My results:
Pool: teste
Queued: Today at 17:21 [manage parallel jobs]
Agent: vm-shared-agent-1 <---- This is my Self Ho
Started: Just now

Starting: Azure CLI login
/usr/bin/az login --service-principal -u *** --password=*** --tenant xxxxxx --allow-no-subscriptions
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "xxxxx",
    "id": "xxxx",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "xxxxx",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "xxxxx",
    "user": {
      "name": "***",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  
Starting: Check Environment Variables
/usr/bin/bash /home/azureuser/myagent/_work/_temp/fb642037-7131-46f9-9676-a2e7b9af9531.sh
ARM_CLIENT_ID: 
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: 
ARM_TENANT_ID: 
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: 

Finishing: Check Environment Variables
**(See ? no variables !!!)**

Terraform Init

ARM_CLIENT_ID: 
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: 
ARM_TENANT_ID: 
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: 

**(See ? No vartiables !!!)**

Initializing the backend...
Initializing modules...
2024-10-18T16:26:54.335Z [DEBUG] Module installer: begin acr
2024-10-18T16:26:54.336Z [DEBUG] Module installer: begin acr_monitoring
2024-10-18T16:26:54.336Z [DEBUG] Module installer: begin aks
2024-10-18T16:26:54.337Z [DEBUG] Module installer: begin aks_monitoring
2024-10-18T16:26:54.337Z [DEBUG] Module installer: begin snet
2024-10-18T16:26:54.337Z [DEBUG] Module installer: begin vnet
╷
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.



And failed. Any help? this is really driving me in nuts. Other approahed I attempted:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Terraform Init"
  env:
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(servicePrincipalId)     
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(servicePrincipalKey)
    ARM_TENANT_ID: $(tenantId)               
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(subscriptionId)   

According with documentation, such variables are kinda built in...but this can't solve anything as well...

The error is due to the terraform variables are not correctly set. In Azure CLI task, you can use logging command to define variable. DevOps non-secret variables will be automatically mapped in to environment. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

The error is due to the terraform environment variables are not set in your Azure CLI login task.
With addSpnToEnvironment: true in the task, it will add service principal id, service principal key and tenant id of the Azure endpoint you chose to the script's execution environment, but they are variables as $(servicePrincipalId), not terraform variables $ARM_CLIENT_ID. You need to map the variables with loggin command ##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_... as below, then the terraform variables are set.
variables:
  - name: ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    value: $(SubscriptionID)                    #<---- You need to set the subscription id manually

steps:
....

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI login'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure ARM Connection'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;]$tenantId"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;]$servicePrincipalId"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;]$servicePrincipalKey"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true

# Test if Env Variables are okay
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Check Environment Variables"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "ARM_CLIENT_ID: $ARM_CLIENT_ID"
      echo "ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"
      echo "ARM_TENANT_ID: $ARM_TENANT_ID"
      echo "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Terraform Init"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      export TF_LOG=DEBUG
      cd project/terraform
      terraform init -backend-config="backend-config-${{ parameters.environment }}.tfvars"

